# EXEs not executing on Win 10

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, path

Recently installed Github Desktop and it wants to find git.exe on the path. I have Git installed in C:/PortableGit. I added C:/PortableGit/bin to my System path. I verified it's there. If I open a CMD window window and type "git" I get 'git' is not recognized as in internal or external command. If I navigate in the CMD window to c:/PortableGit/bin and type "git" I get the same error. Works if I type "git.exe".

How is this happening? Has my system been messed up such that EXE is no longer recognized? Wouldn't other things be badly broken if this were true?

Note: Tried other versions of Git in other locations, same result.

Output of PATH command:
PATH=C:\portablegit\bin;C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\client\bin;C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\client_64\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\CheckPoint\Endpoint Security\Endpoint Common\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\HID Global\ActivClient\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Plantronics\Spokes3G\;C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe PDF iFilter 11 for 64-bit platforms\bin\;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.5.3\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\HID Global\ActivClient\;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ\bin;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ\bin64;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ\tools\c\samples\bin;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\bin;C:\Program Files\Kindel Systems\winprint\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Users\rs02130\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\rs02130\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\rs02130\AppData\Local\Pandoc\;C:\Users\rs02130\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd;C:\Users\rs02130\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\rs02130\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Plantronics\Spokes3G\

My system PATHEXT is .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY

I had a user PATHEXT with .RB. I deleted that.

I can run EXEs from C:/WINDOWS (Notepad, Py)

Comment: What other programs have you attempted to start (`cmd.exe` seems to work, after all)? Have you tried executing it as `.\git.exe` while inside the folder where it is located? Did you add the path with forward slashes to the environment variable `PATH`? If so, have you tried the conventional backslashes? I know NT is supposed to also deal with `/`, but I'm not sure that's true for the environment variables. If you are in that folder and execute `dir git*.*` what does it give you?

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add the output of `echo %path%`.

Comment: This should be asked on https://superuser.com. Your paths are wrong, you screwed up your path extension. `PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a user PATHEXT with .RB. I deleted that. Seems to have fixed all the issues.